# Ozone CFD modelling UDF ansys fluent NMAKE : fatal error U1077 : return code '0x2'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, user-defined-functions, ansys

I am using CFD model to study ozone water interaction

Ozone mass transfer and dissolved ozone decomposition process in water were treated as two user-defined functions (UDF)which are programmed by C language then the two UDFs were loaded into the Ansys Fluent solver. On compilation of codes i am getting error
UDF codes that are used :

```
#include "udf.h"
#define vr 0.0025
#define dg 0.003
#define kl 0.0005
#define cn 6.0

DEFINE_VR_RATE(vol_reac_rate, c, t, r, mw, yi, rr, rr_t)
{
    real *rr
    real yi[0] = C_YI(cell,thread,0)

    *rr = vr*C_VOF(c,t)*C_R(c,t)*yi[0]/mw[0];
   
    return *rr;
} 
 /*define ozone decay volume reaction rate */


DEFINE_MASS_TRANSFER (liq_gas_transfer, cell, thread, from_index,from_species_index, to_index, to_species_index)
{
    real m_lg;
    Thread *gas, *liq;
    gas = THREAD_SUB_THREAD(thread, from_species_index);
    liq = THREAD_SUB_THREAD(thread, to_species_index);

        m_lg = kl*cn/dg *C_VOF(cell,gas); /*unit:[s^-1] */
    
    return (m_lg);
} /*define ozone mass transfer rate */
```

ERROR that I am getting:

```
mass_transfer_udf.c
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(10): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'rr'
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(10): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'real'
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(10): error C2275: 'real': illegal use of this type as an expression
C:\PROGRA~1\ANSYSI~1\ANSYSS~1\v221\fluent\fluent22.1.0\src\main\global.h(198): note: see declaration of 'real'
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(10): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'yi'
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(10): error C2065: 'thread': undeclared identifier
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(10): error C2223: left of '->storageArray' must point to struct/union
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(10): error C2065: 'cell': undeclared identifier
..\..\src\mass_transfer_udf.c(14): warning C4098: 'vol_reac_rate': 'void' function returning a value
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.Error Object: #f
```

How to solve these errors. I am really new at C language.

Comment: It is always better to include enough of your code to provide a [mcve] for best results in getting useful feedback, but in this case, some of the _error/warning_ descriptions provide clear descriptions of the problems in the code shown.  See answer below for some suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The error/warning list is fairly literal.  If you read each description, it tells you the problem it is flagging, and typically, where exactly in your code the problem was flagged.

So for example regarding *"redefinition of formal parameter"*
In most C compilers, a parameter that is not explicitly typed defaults to  `int`.   So in the following:

```
DEFINE_VR_RATE(vol_reac_rate, c, t, r, mw, yi, rr, rr_t)...
```

all o fthe parameters are being defaulted int `int`.  And the error: `redefinition of formal parameter 'rr'` is telling you that `rr`  defined as `int` in the parameter list,  and `real *rr` is attempting to redefine it as *`real`*.

To silence the error, precede each of the parameters with a C type such as `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, and *`real`* (if it is defined in your environment).  Eg:

```
typedef  float real; //(your system may already have this type)

DEFINE_VR_RATE(real vol_reac_rate, int c, int t, int r, real mw, real yi[r], real rr, real rr_t)
```

Note: I am guessing at actual types needed above, change as needed.  Also, because `yi[0]` is used in code, the parameter has to be typed to either an array, or a pointer.  Here I have chosen array, and randomly used `r` as the parameter to size `yi`:  `yi[r]`

**Regarding** *"syntax error: missing ';'"*:
This is simply flagging a missing `;` statement terminator.  Edit this:

```
    real *rr
    real yi[0] = C_YI(cell,thread,0)
```

To this:

```
    //real *rr;  //will already be defined in your parameter list
    yi[0] = C_YI(cell,thread,0); //ditto
```

**Regarding** _*"'real': illegal use of this type as an expression"*
`real` is seen as a type in your environment, as such should be used only to type a variable, but you are using it in an expression like a variable.  This error is likely piggy backing off of one of the previous errors mentioned, and will cease to exist once your function parameters are typed, and the `;` are placed.

**Regarding** _*"'thread': undeclared identifier"*  (also 'cell')
`thread` is not declared anywhere within the scope of where it is being used in the function `C_YI()`.  It may be in a header file, or in another `.C` file, but not in this compiler unit.

**Regarding** *-"left of '->storageArray' must point to struct/union"*
a `struct` or `union` type must occupy the left side of the statement `->storageArray`.  In your code it evidently does not.

**Regarding** *"'vol_reac_rate': 'void' function returning a value"*
The function `vol_reac_rate(...)` is evidently typed as a `void`, but in the body of the function you have a `return x` statement.